# S3 Bucket pricing and performance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I want to know if there are charges for uploading/dropping files in an S3 bucket created in EU region from a lambda function running in the US region.

Also how much of a performance hit it is, to have lambda function and the S3 bucket to be present in these two different regions.

Please help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no charge for data transferred into S3, but you would be charged for data transferred from your Lambda function outside of the region the function executed in (charged at EC2 data transfer rates). You're also charged similarly for data into a Lambda function, if that data originates from outside the Lambda function's region.

For performance, I'd recommend that you test it and also see what the internet has to say about cross-region write performance to S3 (e.g. [takipi/aws-s3-speed](https://github.com/takipi/aws-s3-speed)). Also, consider S3 [Transfer Acceleration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/transfer-acceleration.html) and [Multi-Region Access Points](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/s3-multi-region-access-points-accelerate-performance-availability/).

The configured RAM size of your Lambda functions will impact their network bandwidth, so consider testing with large RAM Lambda functions.

And, generally, be aware of [S3 Performance Guidelines](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/optimizing-performance-guidelines.html).

You might also consider writing to an S3 bucket in the same region and have S3 [replicate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/replication.html) it cross-region.

Comment: Thanks for you response. I didnt understand  "but you would be charged for data transferred from your Lambda function outside of the region the function executed in (charged at EC2 data transfer rates)" this part. Could you please give me an example?

Comment: If a Lambda function running in us-east-1 writes to S3 in eu-west-2, for example, then you are charged for the data transferred from Northern Virginia to London (at $0.02 per GB).

Comment: And this is calculated using outbound data transfer in the s3 pricing estimate page?

Comment: As indicated earlier, EC2 data transfer pricing. This info is all available in the pricing pages afaik.

Comment: Thanks jarmod, I am satisfied with the answer for now :)